# deeplearning4j word2vec output wordvectors

Tags: java, word2vec, deeplearning4j

When I run the sample program `Word2VecRawTextExample.java`

url: 
[ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-0.4-examples/master/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/examples/nlp/word2vec/Word2VecRawTextExample.java ]

to generate word2Vec vectors for a given file of sample sentences, I get different word vector weightings each time I run the process.

I would have thought that given the process is seeded, the result should be the same each time?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the seed like .seed(144) to get consistent results. Please join us on Gitter if you have questions: https://gitter.im/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j